# Background image external style sheet

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hello All
The issue I am currently having is that my background picture does not cover the entire screen and cuts off some hyperlinks I have. "Repo" is supposed to be "Report lost movie", there are also more hyperlinks after it that are cut off. I can still see the hyperlinks when hovering over them though. I've tried many different solutions but none have worked. I am still new to html, css, and coding in general. I know that I can change the style of the picture in the html file, but I decided to use an external style sheet to become more accustomed to that process.

*Both files are in the same folder*
HTML code for image in my .html file

```
<div class="background-image">
      <img src="netflixbg.jpg" alt="" />
```

CSS code for image style in my external style sheet

```
.background-image {
  width: 100vh;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: An `img` tag is not a `background-image`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Would you happen to have any recommendations on how to fix the issue?

Comment: Use a CSS `background-image`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an IMG tag is not a background. You need to do something like below using background-image:

HTML

```
<div class="background-image">
```

CSS

```
.background-image {
  background-image: url("netflixbg.jpg");
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```